# Where does the derivation on the graded algebra of modular forms come from?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry

Let $M$ be the graded algebra of modular forms for $\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$. It is generated by $Q = E_4, R= E_6$, the Eisenstein series of weight $4$ and $6$ respectively. If we define:
$$P = E_2 = 1 - 24\sum_{n\geq 1}\sigma_1(n)q^n$$
and the operator on $M$:
$$\theta(f(q)) = q\frac{df}{dq} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{df}{dz},$$
then we can define a derivation on $M$ by:
$$Df = 12\theta f - kPf$$
where $f$ is a modular form of weight $k$.
I have a few questions about this operator:

**Question 1:** I have heard it said that this is a derivation on $M$. Does this mean that $D(fg) = D(f)g + fD(g)?$ I think this is clear for $\theta$ but it does not seem to be true for $P$. Am I making a mistake here or does derivation mean something else?

**Question 2:** What is the conceptual reason that one would expect there to be a such a derivation on the space of modular forms? What happens for other congruence subgroups?

**Question 2-b** What is the conceptual significance of $P$ behaving almost like a modular form?

Comment: See [the 1-2-3 of modular forms](http://www.paris8.free.fr/The%201-2-3%20of%20Modular%20Forms%20-%20Bruinier,%20der%20Geer,%20Harder,%20Zagier.pdf) p.59. And $P$ isn't a modular form, that's why the Leibniz rule doesn't work for it.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that $D$ is not a derivation in my sense? Also, thanks for the reference.

Comment: It is a derivation on the space of modular forms, but not on the space of holomorphic functions of the upper-half plane. Let $f,g$ be two modular forms of weight $k,m$ then $D( f) = 12 f' - k P f$,$D( g) = 12 g' - m P g$ and $D(fg) = 12 f'g+12 g'f - (k+m) P fg = g D(f)+f D(g)$

Comment: Oh of course. The weight does the work of the Leibiniz rule in some sense, nice!